# How can a generator be converted to a function that returns only the first value yielded by the generator?

Tags: python, function, generator, yield

I have some code that prints out any messages that it receives in a loop:

```
import pytg
import pytg.utils
import pytg.receiver

@pytg.utils.coroutine
def receiver_function(tg_receiver):
    while True:
        message = (yield)
        print(message)

tg_receiver = pytg.receiver.Receiver()
tg_receiver.start()
tg_receiver.message(receiver_function(tg_receiver))
receiver.stop()
```

I want to change this code such that it uses a simple function that halts until a message is encountered and then returns that one message and, of course, control:

```
import pytg
import pytg.receiver

def get_one_message():
    tg_receiver.start()
    while #<insert magic>:
        #<insert magic>
        message = #<insert magic>
    tg.receiver.stop()
    return message

print(get_one_message())
```

How could this be done?

Comment: You can use `next` once on the generator inside the function to just give the first value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pytg’s `Receiver.message` [doesn’t seem to give you access to the generator’s `GeneratorExit`](https://github.com/luckydonald/pytg/blob/67880b28d4eb92a529fde42ad74c51accb6fe8eb/pytg/receiver.py#L214), so you might have to hack it:

```
def get_one_message():
    message = None

    @pytg.utils.coroutine
    def receiver_function(tg_receiver):
        nonlocal message
        message = (yield)

    tg_receiver.start()
    tg_receiver.message(receiver_function(tg_receiver))
    tg_receiver.stop()
    return message
```

Or dive into its undocumented (and therefore unstable) parts, though it’s not a good idea to do so:

```
def get_one_message():
    tg_receiver.start()
    tg_receiver._new_messages.acquire()
    with tg_receiver._queue_access:
        message = tg_receiver._queue.popleft()
    tg_receiver.stop()
    return message
```